# Is scope in ruby considered functional like javascript, or block scope?

Tags: javascript, ruby, scope

Is the scope in Ruby similar or the same to the scope in Javascript i.e. functional scope (a new scope is only created when a function is created) or block scope? If they are different, what are some of the major differences?

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete (I think) list is:

- scripts,
- module definitions,
- class definitions and
- method definitions

create *new* scopes,

- blocks and
- stabby lambda literals

create *nested* scopes (and are the *only* thing that creates nested scopes).

"Block" here means "the special syntactic construct that allows you to pass a single anonymous procedure as the last argument to any method"; it does *not* mean "the parts of an `if` expression" (or similar).